# How to connect local server to live server mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible like connect the local server to the live server database .and fetch the data from that live server database table like users and that users's table's data insert into local server's db.is it possible to connect live server from local server.

Comment: Everything is possible. in your connection string, specify the ip address of the live server database, and you're good to go.

Comment: this is a better place for your question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. You can use live credentials to connect to live database. For Example:

```
$server = "Live Hostname or Live Server IP Address";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "password";
$database   ="dbname";


$con = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error($con));
}
```